# Вывод новостей в цикле php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть блок слайдер, который нужно выводить в цикле. Проблема в том, что нужно выводить сразу по две новости за один прогон. Не могу сообразить как правильно вывести? Ниже код блока, который нужно вывести.

```
    <div>
        <span class="block-content">
            <span class="header-block">
                <span class="number-content">новость 1</span>
                <span class="title-content">Название</span>                             
            </span>
            <span class="text-content">
                <span class="content-text">
                    Текст
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="block-content">
            <span class="header-block">
                <span class="number-content">новость 2</span>
                <span class="title-content">Название</span>                             
            </span>
            <span class="text-content">
                <span class="content-text">
                    Текст
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем выводить по две новости за раз? Можно же просто вставлять разделители (`</div><div>`) раз в две новости. Если предположить, что вы не используете шаблонизаторы, то код может выглядеть так:

```
$news = array(...);

echo('<div>');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++) {
    // Вывод новости
    echo('...');

    // Вывод разделителей
    if ($i > 0 && ($i % 2) == 0 && $i != (count($news) - 1)) {
        echo('</div><div>');
    }
}
echo('</div>');
```

А если вам все-таки хочется выводить по две новости за раз, то можно сделать это так:

```
function output_article($article) {
    echo($article);
}

$news = array(...);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i += 2) {
    echo('<div>');
    output_article($news[$i]);

    if (!empty($news[$i + 1])) {
        output_article($news[$i + 1]);
    }

    echo('</div>');
}
```

Comment: Шаблонизатор использую Smarty. Сейчас попробую это всё совместить.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i+=2){
   echo $arr[$i];
   echo $arr[$i+1];
   echo '</br>';
}
```

можно таким образом, смотря какой массив